# How do I vertically center an image in fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation, fullpage.js

I'm building a site using fullpage.js and Foundation. I'm trying to vertically center an image inside of a section and I'm having no luck.

I've tried this:

https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

I think that the issue has something to do with the fp-tableCell div that fullpage.js creates.

```
<div id="first-section" class="section sTop active">
        <div id="first-section-row" class="row inner">
            <div id="slide_1_wrapper" class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <h1 class="title">Hello!</h1>
                <h2 class="subtitle">My name is Whatever</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="main-picture-wrapper" class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <img id="main-picture" src="img/headshot.jpg" alt="my_picture">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried the CSS from the article above with no luck:

```
#main-picture {
    max-height: 400px;
}
#main-picture-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#slide-1-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#first-section:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
```

[Screenshot of the rendered html, showing the fp-tableCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx1LB.png)

Comment: try giving the wrapper ID or class `position: relative` and then the image class or ID `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;` - Rough Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rrh5c04a/

Comment: By default fullpage.js uses the option `verticalCentered:true`, so any image you add will be automatically centered unless you change it by using CSS.

Comment: Woohoo Michael your way worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in html

```
<div id="page">
       <div id="content_container" class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
               <div id="main-picture-wrapper">
                    <img id="main-picture" src="keyboard_search.png" alt="my_picture">
               </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

in css

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#page{display:table;overflow:hidden;margin:0px auto;}

#content_container{display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}

#main-picture-wrapper p{text-align:center;}
html,body{height:100%;}
#page{height:100%;width:100%; max-width:600px; text-align:center;}
.bannerimg{width:100%;max-width:600px;margin:0px auto;}
```

may help you

Answer (score 0):

By default fullpage.js uses the option `verticalCentered:true`, so any image you add will be automatically centered unless you change it by using CSS.

You can easily see this in any [demo online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) or in any of [the provided examples](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 0):

From Michael in the comments:

Try giving the wrapper ID or class position: relative and then the image class or ID position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; - Rough Demo: jsfiddle.net/rrh5c04a